# How can I catch web api return message on Devextreme datagrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datagrid, devextreme, devexpress-mvc

I a using [DevExpress MVC DataGrid](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/Overview/jQuery/Light/) in my Asp.Net MVC project, I would like to know how to catch the events in the client side for example after a row is inserted or updated.

See my sample code below:

```
    @(Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid().ID("MyId").DataSource(d => d.WebApi().Controller("MyWebApi").Key("MyTableId")
........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the events described below:

```
    .OnEditingStart(@<text> function(e) { logEvent("EditingStart"); } </text>)
    .OnInitNewRow(@<text> function(e) { logEvent("InitNewRow"); } </text>)
    .OnRowInserting(@<text> function(e) { logEvent("RowInserting"); } </text>)
    .OnRowInserted(@<text> function(e) { logEvent("RowInserted"); } </text>)
    .OnRowUpdating(@<text> function(e) { logEvent("RowUpdating"); } </text>)
    .OnRowUpdated(@<text> function(e) { logEvent("RowUpdated"); } </text>)
    .OnRowRemoving(@<text> function(e) { logEvent("RowRemoving"); } </text>)
    .OnRowRemoved(@<text> function(e) { logEvent("RowRemoved"); } </text>)
```

Yo can see it working on this [demo from DevExpress](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/RowEditingAndEditingEvents/Mvc/Light/)

Answer (score 0):

There is the  [official DevExtreme demo](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/RowEditingAndEditingEvents/Mvc/Light/) where illustrated how to implement CRUD operations by using WebAPI